# How can I parse a specific range of number values within a column using Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

What I am trying to do is a little complicated, but I am hoping it will be very simple to someone here. Basically, I have a text file that contains data separated into 3 columns (they are x,y,z coordinates, hence the 3 columns). I need the 12 largest values of the first 72 entries that column, and then I want them averaged. Is there a simple way to go about this? If this could be done without Pandas, even better.

Comment: kindly share sample dataframe and expected output

Comment: File containing data to be parsed is of the form    
 `0.1666650953180095  0.2499994896894790  0.0000000000000000
 0.0000000000000000  0.1666670068736806  0.0555554593304635
 0.1666650953180095  0.4166664965631597  0.0555554593304635`     
and output would ideally return the average of the 12 highest numbers.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve].  Do not expect SO users to provide you with the complete solution and code it for you.  Get started, show us a sample data set and expected result, and how your attempt does not work.